# Meaning for 昔から大好きな親戚の姉さん

Tags: translation, particle-の, relative-clauses, kinship-terms

I sometimes hear 姉さん used as just another way of addressing an older woman but I don't understand the usage of 親戚の姉さん. 親戚(shinseki) is relative so does Shinseki no Nesan mean the literal older sister of a relative, or something else?
The full fragment I want to get the meaning of is 昔から大好きな親戚の姉さん.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is getting downvotes? The literal translation of 親戚の姉さん would be "(a) relative's older sister", but that seems like a potentially weird thing to say. For example, if the relative was my mother I wouldn't say "my mother's sister". I would say "my aunt". Is there anything I'm missing here, or is it nothing more than my simple translation?

Answer (score 4):

This 'の' should most naturally be regarded as an apposition, rather than possession. So it refers to a 姉さん, who is your 親戚.

Looking up a dictionary, the definition of the word 姉さん usually starts with these two:

1. older sister (広辞苑: >「あね」の軽い尊敬語…)
2. young lady (広辞苑: > 若い女性を呼ぶ称。)

In the phrase 親戚の姉さん, it falls somewhat in between. I think "a female, comparative to your older sister (existent or not) in age" would be a fair interpretation. (I initially felt that the phrase typically refers to a young person, but I won't find it odd if the speaker is 55 yo and his '親戚の姉さん' is 60 yo.)

So it refers to someone in your relatives, who is a little older than you. Could be your grandfather's sister's granddaughter or anything. Note that the speaker's real sisters will not be included in the phrase.

---

"A relative's older sister", on the other hand, is a possible interpretation but weird without context. As you noticed, a relative's sister *is* your relative, so it isn't logical to mention separately. Unless that relative is known beforehand, as in this (possibly unnatural) random example I came up with.

> この前親戚から仕事を受けました．その親戚の姉さんが，今回の依頼主です． *An older sister of that relative (with whom we had a contract last time) is our client this time.*

Comment: So while 親戚の姉さん falls under "a female relative slightly older than you" it does not mean a relative who is also your older sister?

Comment: @Alex Yes. While the dictionary definition of [親戚](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A6%AA%E6%88%9A-538091#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) doesn't exclude it, 家族 and 親戚 are mutually exclusive in standard usage. That is, when I hear 親戚, I assume it's someone from the speaker's relative but outside his/her family. So your 姉 (as in older sister) will usually not be among your 親戚.